# Merging virtual and implementation inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, ambiguous

I have a base and derived virtual class, but I encounter ambiguity when the derived implentation inherits from both the base-implementation and the derived interface.

[image]

I know aliasing can be used to specify that methods and variables from the base implementation. What are good practices for this problem in C++?

Comment: This is essentially diamond problem. Possible solutions are aggregation or virtual inheritance.

Comment: Are the interface & implementation representing inheritance or the *pointer to implementation* pattern?

Comment: It is supposed to represent direct inheritance, both data members and methods are called directly from derived classes without dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

This is 'The diamond problem', which in C++ is solvable by the using the virtual-keyword in inheritance:

```
class B : virtual public A
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance